# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "data" : hostPath type check failed: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data is not a directory

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims

Below is my YAML for volume mounting:

```
initContainers:

  - name: fix-permissions
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  - name: increase-vm-max-map
    image: busybox
    command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
  - name: increase-fd-ulimit
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
  volumes:
    - name: data
      hostPath: 
        path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Even after changing type to DirectoryOrCreate, it shows the error:

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "data" : hostPath type check failed: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data is not a directory

How can I fix this ??

Comment: What kind of cluster do you use? Minikube, kubeadm or managed by cloud GKE, AKS, EKS? Which version of Kubernetes do you use? [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83125) was the similar problem.

Comment: I am using kubeadm cluster having the kubernetes version 1

Comment: Did you see on link which I send? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a volumeMounts inside your container:

```
containers:
  - name: increase-fd-ulimit
    volumeMounts:
      - name: data
        mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

and add a volumeClaimTemplates inside your sts:

```
spec: 
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: data
        namespace: your_namespace
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 200Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
```